# Overridable methods cannot be static: How else can I do what I'm trying to do?

Tags: c#

I have a series of static classes that I use to get strings for enum values.  They all look something like this:

```
public static class MyEnumToString
{
  private static Dictionary<MyEnum, string> map
   = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>();

  public static string Get(MyEnum type)
  {
    PopulateEmptyMap();
    return map[type];
  }

  static void PopulateEmptyMap()
  {
    if (!map.Any())
    {
      PopulateMap();
    }
  }

  private static void PopulateMap()
  {
    map[MyEnum.enum1] = "string for enum 1";
    map[MyEnum.enum2] = "string for enum 2";
  }
}
```

I have multiple classes like this, that differ in the Enum type they use, and the string values.  Clearly, I should combine the classes to reduce duplicated code.

What I tried doing was create generic base class so that it can handle any type, then implement the PopulateMap for the inherited classes.  If it were possible, it would look something like this:

```
public static class TypeToString<TType>
{
  public static Dictionary<TType, string> map
   = new Dictionary<TType, string>();

  public static string Get(TType type)
  {
    PopulateEmptyMap();
    return map[type];
  }

  static void PopulateEmptyMap()
  {
    if (!map.Any())
    {
      PopulateMap();
    }
  }

  public abstract static void PopulateMap();
}

public static class MyEnumToString: TypeToString<MyEnum>
{
  public static void PopulateMap()
  {
    map[MyEnum.enum1] = "string for enum 1";
    map[MyEnum.enum2] = "string for enum 2";
  }
}
```

I had to make the Dictionary and the method PopulateMap public, because apparently generic classes cannot have protected or protected-internal members.  Having to make that public isn't ideal, but not a deal-breaker.

What I am getting hung up on is the fact that "overridable methods cannot be static", so my PopulateMap method cannot be both abstract and static.  And if it's not static, it can't be called from other static methods.  And if it's not abstract, then the inheriting classes' PopulateMap doesn't get called.

This version doesn't even build.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do and still keep my class static?  I'd really like to avoid having to have an instantiated TypeToString object every time I want to call TypeToString.Get().

Comment: Hint: why don't create attribute for enum create extension method that extract string from attribute?

Comment: You could have the static code create an instance of a non-static class local to the template, which then contains all of your virtual functions, and have the static class route everything through a single instance of that handler class.  You should also be able to parameterize the overloaded function rather than making it virtual.  I.e.: Have `MyEnumToString<X> when X: Enum1`, and one `when X: Eum2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a handy extension method, as I'm guessing you're trying to map some description text to an enum value:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        var field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        if (field == null)
            return value.ToString();

        var attribute = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                             .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
                             .SingleOrDefault();

        return attribute != null
            ? attribute.Description
            : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
public enum Foo
{
    [Description("Hello")]
    Bar,

    [Description("World")]
    Baz
}

var value = Foo.Bar;
var description = value.GetDescription(); // Hello
```

Depending on your needs, you could cache the descriptions if reflection proves to be too slow for you, just modify the `GetDescription` method.

---

**EDIT:** to account for the additional info in the comment.

As it looks like you need something more extensible, you could use a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class DescriptionEntryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public DescriptionEntryAttribute(string key, string value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Which would let you to do this:

```
public enum Foo
{
    [DescriptionEntry("Name", "Hello")]
    [DescriptionEntry("Title", "Some title")]
    Bar,

    [DescriptionEntry("Name", "World")]
    [DescriptionEntry("Title", "Some title")]
    Baz
}
```

Now, to read this thing, I'd advise you to store it in a cache like that:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, DescriptionCache> Caches = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, DescriptionCache>();

    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value, string key)
    {
        var enumType = value.GetType();
        var cache = Caches.GetOrAdd(enumType, type => new DescriptionCache(type));
        return cache.GetDescription(value, key);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetValuesFromDescription<TEnum>(string key, string description)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        var cache = Caches.GetOrAdd(typeof(TEnum), type => new DescriptionCache(type));
        return cache.GetValues(key, description).Select(value => (TEnum)(object)value);
    }

    private class DescriptionCache
    {
        private readonly ILookup<Enum, Tuple<string, string>> _items;
        private readonly ILookup<Tuple<string, string>, Enum> _reverse;

        public DescriptionCache(Type enumType)
        {
            if (!enumType.IsEnum)
                throw new ArgumentException("Not an enum");

            _items = (from value in Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<Enum>()
                      let field = enumType.GetField(value.ToString())
                      where field != null
                      from attribute in field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionEntryAttribute), false).OfType<DescriptionEntryAttribute>()
                      select new {value, key = attribute.Key, description = attribute.Value})
                .ToLookup(i => i.value, i => Tuple.Create(i.key, i.description));

            _reverse = (from grp in _items
                        from description in grp
                        select new {value = grp.Key, description})
                .ToLookup(i => i.description, i => i.value);
        }

        public string GetDescription(Enum value, string key)
        {
            var tuple = _items[value].FirstOrDefault(i => i.Item1 == key);
            return tuple != null ? tuple.Item2 : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Enum> GetValues(string key, string description)
        {
            return _reverse[Tuple.Create(key, description)];
        }
    }
}
```

This way:

- `Foo.Bar.GetDescription("Name")` returns `"Hello"`
- `EnumExtensions.GetValuesFromDescription<Foo>("Title", "Some title")` returns a sequence containing `Foo.Bar` and `Foo.Baz`

That should be enough to get you started, now you should tweak it to your needs. For instance, you could use an enum instead of a string for the keys, it would help avoid typing mistakes, but I don't know if this would suit your needs.

Comment: A few questions about your response:

1.  How would I cache the descriptions in the GetDescription method?  
2.  Is it possible for this to work for multiple string types?  While I didn't describe this in the OP, I have multiple classes with dictionaries for a single enum, giving different types of strings for the same enum?  
3.  Is it possible to do this in reverse, so that given a string you can query which enum it goes with?  Again, this wasn't in the original question, but some of my classes have dictionaries going the other way.

Comment: @PortMan Ok I've made a much more detailed example

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that static methods and variables are essentially not inherited. They are variables that don't act on instances of the class themselves, but provide some functionality to the class.

So you have a bunch of different enums, and you want to populate them based on different stuff. So let's look at what parts you have, and what is common:

- PopulateMap: Not common
- Enum type: Not common
- Storage variable: Common
- Populate Map if empty: Common

So all you really want is a way to populate the map once, when it's used. There is already a class for this, it's called `Lazy`. Using that, the code becomes:

```
public abstract class TypeToString<Type>
{
    protected TypeToString()
    {
        storage = new Lazy<Dictionary<Type, string>>(GetMap);
    }
    private Lazy<Dictionary<Type, string>> storage;
    protected abstract Dictionary<Type, string> GetMap();
    public string Get(Type t) {return storage.Value[t];}
}
public class MyEnumToString : TypeToString<MyEnum>
{
    protected override Dictionary<MyEnum, string> GetMap()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public static Get(MyEnum e) { return new MyEnumToString.Get(e); }
}
```

Alternatively, you can decorate your enums with a `[DescriptionAttribute]` and then create a method to get the description of a specific enum. This is what I did when I was faced with a similar problem. (Be sure to cache the results for the enum, as it used reflection which was slow.)

Comment: Since it's not static, I will have to have an instantiated MyEnumToString object in order to call the Get() method, correct?

That's the problem that I'm trying to find a work-around for:  how to do this while without having to have instantiated objects.

I definitely see the value in your solution over mine -- why invent my own wheel when it's already there waiting for me to use?

Comment: @Portman Again, if you just want to convert a number of enums to strings, and you know the values ahead of time, I would go with the solution of using the [DescriptionAttribute] and checking those values.  Another question is why you want to not instantiate objects?  Objects are cheap.  Unless you have a problem, don't worry about object instantiation.

Comment: I'm not sure if the [DescriptionAttribute] will work for me, since a) I need to be able to convert an enum into more than one type of string (I currently have multiple enum->string classes for a single enum), and b) I need to be able to do the reverse, converting string->enum.  
As to why I don't want to instantiate objects, it's purely to avoid having to have the extra line in the code instantiating the object.  I'm new to C#, and I guess I'm trying to make C# act more like a functional language than an OO language.

Comment: @Portman You have a few options, then.  1) Add a static method to each class that gets the value for that type and handles instantiation (I've updated my answer with that).  2) Create one class that has a different method for each type of conversion "GetStringForAccount(MyEnum e)".  3) Create extension methods to convert the enums.  This is the approach I would take, given your additional constraints.